# How to find the minimum in JSON in Python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, for-loop, min

There is a part of a JSON file:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "platinum": 4,
                "visible": true,
                "order_type": "sell",
                "user": {
                    "reputation": 5,
                    "region": "en",
                    "last_seen": "2022-11-17T08:15:43.360+00:00",
                    "ingame_name": "Noxxat",
                    "id": "5b50d73859d885026b523cd1",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "status": "offline"
                },
                "platform": "pc",
                "region": "en",
                "creation_date": "2020-09-04T15:30:41.000+00:00",
                "last_update": "2021-11-19T09:41:43.000+00:00",
                "id": "5f525da1c98cd000d7513813"
            },
            {
                "order_type": "sell",
                "visible": true,
                "quantity": 2,
                "platinum": 6,
                "user": {
                    "reputation": 3,
                    "region": "en",
                    "last_seen": "2022-11-18T14:22:53.023+00:00",
                    "ingame_name": "Dhatman",
                    "id": "5b79921649262103f74b6585",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "status": "offline"
                },
                "platform": "pc",
                "region": "en",
                "creation_date": "2020-11-06T10:32:32.000+00:00",
                "last_update": "2022-10-11T16:51:55.000+00:00",
                "id": "5fa526406ff3660486ef556c"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "visible": true,
                "platinum": 5,
                "order_type": "sell",
                "user": {
                    "reputation": 4,
                    "region": "en",
                    "last_seen": "2022-11-18T18:31:49.199+00:00",
                    "ingame_name": "TheronGuardxx",
                    "avatar": "user/avatar/5e235e94ab7656047a86f70c.png?7b1e90d474a62c6ba3c2d3ef06aed927",
                    "id": "5e235e94ab7656047a86f70c",
                    "status": "offline"
                },
                "platform": "pc",
                "region": "en",
                "creation_date": "2020-12-17T22:46:57.000+00:00",
                "last_update": "2022-10-15T23:37:01.000+00:00",
                "id": "5fdbdfe13e8c4f017f5e3352"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to find the minimum amount of platinum in this file?
As I understand it, I need to make a loop that will go through the entire file and assign a new value to the variable min if the current amount of platinum is less than the amount currently written in min.

But what should the code look like?

At the moment I have written a block that finds the amount of platinum, the seller's alias and the number of items from the last element of the JSON-file.

```
num = 1
flagSell = 0

while flagSell == 0:
    if r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["user"]['status'] == 'ingame':
        if r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["region"] == 'en':
            if r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["order_type"] == 'sell':
                min = r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["platinum"]
                author = r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["user"]["ingame_name"]
                quantity = r_json["payload"]["orders"][len(r_json["payload"]["orders"]) - num]["quantity"]
                flagSell = 1
            else:
                num += 1
        else:
            num += 1
    else:
        num += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use bult-in function `min()` to find minimum order according to the `platinum` key (`data` is your dictionary from the question):

```py
min_order = min(data["payload"]["orders"], key=lambda o: o["platinum"])

print("Min Platinum =", min_order["platinum"])
print("Name =", min_order["user"]["ingame_name"])
print("Quantity =", min_order["quantity"])
```

Prints:

```
Min Platinum = 4
Name = Noxxat
Quantity = 1
```

---

EDIT: If you want to search for a minimum in orders where `order_type == 'sell'`:

```py
min_order = min(
    (o for o in data["payload"]["orders"] if o["order_type"] == "sell"),
    key=lambda o: o["platinum"],
)

print("Min Platinum =", min_order["platinum"])
print("Name =", min_order["user"]["ingame_name"])
print("Quantity =", min_order["quantity"])
```

Comment: It seems to be working. How can I make it so that the search is only for items where `'order_type' == 'sell'`?
I tried inserting `min_order = min(r_json["payload"]["orders"], key=lambda o: o["platinum"])` in my last `if` but looks like it didn`t work